# C# MySQL id column not working correctly

Tags: c#, mysql, auto-increment

I'm trying to insert some data into a local MySQL database.

Some fields have an UNIQUE index.

The ID field in my database has a PRIMARY_KEY assigned and a AUTO_INCREMENT index.

When i want to add data to the database with an unique index, it works fine but under certain conditions.. It does add the data, but.. It just keeps on counting. What i want to explain with this, is that whenever I put incorrect data into my form (an duplicated entry) the ID field keeps on counting.

i.e. adding username; hi, id is 1

adding username hi, id is 2, but doesn't add to the database

adding username bye, Id in the database is 3 (my problem)

```
    private bool authenticateLaptop(string leerling, string laptop, string merk, string serienummer, string ruimte, string locatie, string status, string naam, string olcnummer, bool uitgifte)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(@"server=" + Settings.Default.databaseServer + ";username=" + Settings.Default.databaseUsername + ";password=" + Settings.Default.databasePassword + ";database=" + Settings.Default.databaseName))
        {
            connection.Open();
            try
            {
                string query = null;
                using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    query = "INSERT INTO inventarisatie (hnummer, merk, serienummer, ruimte, locatie, status, inbezitvan, olcnummer, uitgifte) VALUES (@laptop, @merk, @serienummer, @ruimte, @locatie, @status, @inbezitvan, @olcnummer, @uitgifte)";
                    command.CommandText = query;
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@laptop", laptop);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@merk", merk);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@serienummer", serienummer);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ruimte", ruimte);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@locatie", locatie);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", status);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@inbezitvan", naam);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@olcnummer", olcnummer);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uitgifte", uitgifte);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    loadData();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                switch (ex.Number)
                {
                    case 1062:
                        if (ex.Message.Contains("hnummer"))
                            MessageBox.Show("Deze laptop staat al in de lijst");
                        if (ex.Message.Contains("serienummer"))
                            MessageBox.Show("Dit serienummer staat al in de lijst");
                        if (ex.Message.Contains("olcnummer"))
                            MessageBox.Show("Dit OLC nummer staat al in de lijst");
                        loadData();
                        break;
                    default:
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                        break;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                {
                    connection.Close();
                    loadData();

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Sql create table

```
query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `inventarisatie`;CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventarisatie` (`id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  `merk` varchar(6) NOT NULL,  `serienummer` varchar(6) NOT NULL,  `hnummer` varchar(6) NOT NULL,  `ruimte` varchar(4) NOT NULL, `locatie` varchar(1) NOT NULL,  `status` char(1) NOT NULL,  `inbezitvan` varchar(20) NOT NULL,  `olcnummer` varchar(3) NOT NULL,  `uitgifte` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),  UNIQUE KEY (hnummer, serienummer, olcnummer)) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;";
```

Answer (score 1):

if id is autoincremental then no needs to use it in insert

```
query = "INSERT INTO inventarisatie (hnummer, merk, serienummer, ruimte, locatie, status, inbezitvan, olcnummer, uitgifte) VALUES (@laptop, @merk, @serienummer, @ruimte, @locatie, @status, @inbezitvan, @olcnummer, @uitgifte)";
```

then remove

```
 command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
```

Update:
As I see you have 3 unique keys and exception is that if you insert to table **hnummer** or **serienummer** or **olcnummer** which is already in db then you will have exception. And please not you key are 3 different. so you should make sure that none of them exists in db

If you need it to be one key from 3 columns, which i think maybe you need but i am not usre then, it should be

> UNIQUE KEY (hnummer, serienummer, olcnummer)

Comment: I already did that, and it gives the same probleme whenever i get a MySQL exception about a duplicated entry

Comment: @user2989034: On which field is it throwing an exception.

Comment: @user2989034: You better add result of `show create table inventarisatie ` to your posting.

Comment: I have 3 fields wich have a UNIQUE index, serienummer, hnummer and olcnummer, btw posted my table creation code

Comment: unfortunately its giving me the same problem. I changed my database query to: (see thread) but i still have the same problem. are there any other things that can cause this? because this isnt doing this when im inserting data via PHPMyAdmin

Comment: @user2989034 can you please update your question with real insert query? and error which you get?

Comment: I already updated the question, And the error im geting is that i got an duplicated entry, so the data (except the id) doesnt import into the database, but i import data wich is right, im not getting the right ID number

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat  Then it just works as it supposed to do it, but without an UNIQUE key i wouldnt get any errors

Comment: @user2989034 you mean with or without? So why i ask you to remove just to show you that issue is in unique key. Try to do select on that unique keys and see if you have data for it in you table. Because idea of unique key dont allow you to insert that key twice

Comment: I mean when ever i have the UNIQUE key deleted off my fields, i'm not getting any problems with the ID field :) so that's not the problem. With other words, i already tried that ;)

Comment: @user2989034 yes its what i mean that if you dont have UNIQUE key then you dont have any problems with insert. Thats why issue is with unique key.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat  Well, cant i fix that? D: (By the help of you guys)

Comment: @user2989034 Before insert do select if there is any record whit that unique key

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat What? can you please explain that a bit more detailed.

Comment: @user2989034 i tried few times to explain you...  Read about Unique key to understand how they are working. your problem is not in ID but in unique key. if you want me to help. Please dump query which you run not just php var but print it + give me data from your table save them to file and upload somewhere

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I already posted that in my original thread, its in the whole method, at the end of the thread i have added the query i'm using to create the databases? Or dont you mean that?

Answer (score 0):

Your id is auto increment  **MySQL assigned sequence numbers automatically**  so remove @**Volodymyr Bilyachat** said

```
query = "INSERT INTO inventarisatie (hnummer, merk, serienummer, ruimte, locatie, status, inbezitvan, olcnummer, uitgifte) VALUES (@laptop, @merk, @serienummer, @ruimte, @locatie, @status, @inbezitvan, @olcnummer, @uitgifte)";
```

**so remove**

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
```

Comment: I already did that, and it gives the same probleme whenever i get a MySQL exception about a duplicated entry